# How to mount a blu-ray drive?

Tags: mount, dvd, disk

Maybe it is for the best to close this question. This has nothing to do with a bluray drive in general anymore. Probably a hardware defect. I will try to test it with a windows system and different cables again... Thx so far.

I have a bluray/dvd/cdrom drive with SATA.
Ubuntu wont find it under /dev/sd

```
wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg2'  rwrw-- : 'HL-DT-ST' 'BDDVDRW CH08LS10'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

cdrecord -scanbus 
scsibus2:
    2,0,0   200) 'HL-DT-ST' 'BDDVDRW CH08LS10' '2.00' Removable CD-ROM
```

fdisk dont even lists it. Ubuntu only automounts blank DVDs, but neither CDROM nor Blurays. I also changed the sata slot, sata cable and the power cable. The drive works with a windows system.

This happens when I try to mount:

```
sudo mount -t auto /dev/scd0 /media/bluray
mount: you must specify the filesystem type
```

I tried all filesystems there are.

I also installed makemkv. It finds the drive but not the disc.
[image]

Here is my /dev

```
ls -al /dev
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  17 root root          4420 2011-11-25 19:36 .
drwxr-xr-x  28 root root          4096 2011-11-25 07:12 ..
crw-------   1 root root       10, 235 2011-11-25 19:28 autofs
-rw-r--r--   1 root root           630 2011-11-25 19:28 .blkid.tab
-rw-r--r--   1 root root           630 2011-11-25 19:28 .blkid.tab.old
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root           700 2011-11-25 19:27 block
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root           100 2011-11-25 19:27 bsg
crw-------   1 root root       10, 234 2011-11-25 19:28 btrfs-control
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root            60 2011-11-25 19:27 bus
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root          3820 2011-11-25 19:28 char
crw-------   1 root root        5,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 console
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root            11 2011-11-25 19:28 core -> /proc/kcore
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root            60 2011-11-25 19:28 cpu
crw-------   1 root root       10,  60 2011-11-25 19:28 cpu_dma_latency
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root           140 2011-11-25 19:27 disk
crw-------   1 root root       10,  61 2011-11-25 19:28 ecryptfs
crw-rw----   1 root video      29,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 fb0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root            13 2011-11-25 19:28 fd -> /proc/self/fd
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root        1,   7 2011-11-25 19:28 full
crw-rw-rw-   1 root fuse       10, 229 2011-11-25 19:28 fuse
crw-------   1 root root      251,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 hidraw0
crw-------   1 root root      251,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 hidraw1
crw-------   1 root root       10, 228 2011-11-25 19:28 hpet
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root            14 2011-11-25 19:27 .initramfs -> /run/initramfs
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root           220 2011-11-25 19:28 input
crw-------   1 root root        1,  11 2011-11-25 19:28 kmsg
srw-rw-rw-   1 root root             0 2011-11-25 19:28 log
brw-rw----   1 root disk        7,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 loop0
brw-rw----   1 root disk        7,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 loop1
brw-rw----   1 root disk        7,   2 2011-11-25 19:28 loop2
brw-rw----   1 root disk        7,   3 2011-11-25 19:28 loop3
brw-rw----   1 root disk        7,   4 2011-11-25 19:28 loop4
brw-rw----   1 root disk        7,   5 2011-11-25 19:28 loop5
brw-rw----   1 root disk        7,   6 2011-11-25 19:28 loop6
brw-rw----   1 root disk        7,   7 2011-11-25 19:28 loop7
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root            60 2011-11-25 19:27 mapper
crw-------   1 root root       10, 227 2011-11-25 19:28 mcelog
crw-r-----   1 root kmem        1,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 mem
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root            60 2011-11-25 19:27 net
crw-------   1 root root       10,  59 2011-11-25 19:28 network_latency
crw-------   1 root root       10,  58 2011-11-25 19:28 network_throughput
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root        1,   3 2011-11-25 19:28 null
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      195,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 nvidia0
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root      195, 255 2011-11-25 19:28 nvidiactl
crw-------   1 root root        1,  12 2011-11-25 19:28 oldmem
crw-r-----   1 root kmem        1,   4 2011-11-25 19:28 port
crw-------   1 root root      108,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 ppp
crw-------   1 root root       10,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 psaux
crw-rw-rw-   1 root tty         5,   2 2011-11-25 20:00 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root             0 2011-11-25 19:27 pts
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 ram0
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 ram1
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,  10 2011-11-25 19:28 ram10
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,  11 2011-11-25 19:28 ram11
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,  12 2011-11-25 19:28 ram12
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,  13 2011-11-25 19:28 ram13
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,  14 2011-11-25 19:28 ram14
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,  15 2011-11-25 19:28 ram15
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   2 2011-11-25 19:28 ram2
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   3 2011-11-25 19:28 ram3
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   4 2011-11-25 19:28 ram4
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   5 2011-11-25 19:28 ram5
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   6 2011-11-25 19:28 ram6
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   7 2011-11-25 19:28 ram7
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   8 2011-11-25 19:28 ram8
brw-rw----   1 root disk        1,   9 2011-11-25 19:28 ram9
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root        1,   8 2011-11-25 19:28 random
crw-rw-r--+  1 root root       10,  62 2011-11-25 19:28 rfkill
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root             4 2011-11-25 19:28 rtc -> rtc0
crw-------   1 root root      254,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 rtc0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root             3 2011-11-25 19:38 scd0 -> sr0
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 sda
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 sda1
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,   2 2011-11-25 19:28 sda2
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,   3 2011-11-25 19:28 sda3
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,   5 2011-11-25 19:28 sda5
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,   6 2011-11-25 19:28 sda6
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,  16 2011-11-25 19:28 sdb
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,  17 2011-11-25 19:28 sdb1
crw-rw----   1 root disk       21,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 sg0
crw-rw----   1 root disk       21,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 sg1
crw-rw----+  1 root cdrom      21,   2 2011-11-25 19:28 sg2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root             8 2011-11-25 19:28 shm -> /run/shm
crw-------   1 root root       10, 231 2011-11-25 19:28 snapshot
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root           280 2011-11-25 19:28 snd
brw-rw----+  1 root cdrom      11,   0 2011-11-25 19:38 sr0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root            15 2011-11-25 19:28 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root            15 2011-11-25 19:28 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root            15 2011-11-25 19:28 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw-   1 root tty         5,   0 2011-11-25 19:35 tty
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 tty0
crw-------   1 root root        4,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 tty1
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  10 2011-11-25 19:28 tty10
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  11 2011-11-25 19:28 tty11
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  12 2011-11-25 19:28 tty12
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  13 2011-11-25 19:28 tty13
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  14 2011-11-25 19:28 tty14
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  15 2011-11-25 19:28 tty15
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  16 2011-11-25 19:28 tty16
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  17 2011-11-25 19:28 tty17
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  18 2011-11-25 19:28 tty18
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  19 2011-11-25 19:28 tty19
crw-------   1 root root        4,   2 2011-11-25 19:28 tty2
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  20 2011-11-25 19:28 tty20
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  21 2011-11-25 19:28 tty21
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  22 2011-11-25 19:28 tty22
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  23 2011-11-25 19:28 tty23
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  24 2011-11-25 19:28 tty24
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  25 2011-11-25 19:28 tty25
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  26 2011-11-25 19:28 tty26
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  27 2011-11-25 19:28 tty27
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  28 2011-11-25 19:28 tty28
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  29 2011-11-25 19:28 tty29
crw-------   1 root root        4,   3 2011-11-25 19:28 tty3
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  30 2011-11-25 19:28 tty30
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  31 2011-11-25 19:28 tty31
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  32 2011-11-25 19:28 tty32
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  33 2011-11-25 19:28 tty33
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  34 2011-11-25 19:28 tty34
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  35 2011-11-25 19:28 tty35
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  36 2011-11-25 19:28 tty36
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  37 2011-11-25 19:28 tty37
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  38 2011-11-25 19:28 tty38
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  39 2011-11-25 19:28 tty39
crw-------   1 root root        4,   4 2011-11-25 19:28 tty4
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  40 2011-11-25 19:28 tty40
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  41 2011-11-25 19:28 tty41
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  42 2011-11-25 19:28 tty42
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  43 2011-11-25 19:28 tty43
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  44 2011-11-25 19:28 tty44
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  45 2011-11-25 19:28 tty45
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  46 2011-11-25 19:28 tty46
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  47 2011-11-25 19:28 tty47
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  48 2011-11-25 19:28 tty48
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  49 2011-11-25 19:28 tty49
crw-------   1 root root        4,   5 2011-11-25 19:28 tty5
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  50 2011-11-25 19:28 tty50
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  51 2011-11-25 19:28 tty51
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  52 2011-11-25 19:28 tty52
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  53 2011-11-25 19:28 tty53
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  54 2011-11-25 19:28 tty54
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  55 2011-11-25 19:28 tty55
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  56 2011-11-25 19:28 tty56
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  57 2011-11-25 19:28 tty57
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  58 2011-11-25 19:28 tty58
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  59 2011-11-25 19:28 tty59
crw-------   1 root root        4,   6 2011-11-25 19:28 tty6
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  60 2011-11-25 19:28 tty60
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  61 2011-11-25 19:28 tty61
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  62 2011-11-25 19:28 tty62
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,  63 2011-11-25 19:28 tty63
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,   7 2011-11-25 19:28 tty7
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,   8 2011-11-25 19:28 tty8
crw--w----   1 root tty         4,   9 2011-11-25 19:28 tty9
crw-------   1 root root        5,   3 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyprintk
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  64 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS0
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  65 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS1
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  74 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS10
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  75 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS11
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  76 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS12
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  77 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS13
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  78 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS14
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  79 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS15
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  80 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS16
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  81 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS17
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  82 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS18
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  83 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS19
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  66 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS2
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  84 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS20
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  85 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS21
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  86 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS22
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  87 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS23
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  88 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS24
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  89 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS25
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  90 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS26
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  91 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS27
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  92 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS28
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  93 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS29
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  67 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS3
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  94 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS30
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  95 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS31
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  68 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS4
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  69 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS5
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  70 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS6
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  71 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS7
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  72 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS8
crw-rw----   1 root dialout     4,  73 2011-11-25 19:28 ttyS9
d    rwxr-xr-x   3 root root            60 2011-11-25 19:28 .udev
crw-r-----   1 root root       10, 223 2011-11-25 19:28 uinput
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root        1,   9 2011-11-25 19:28 urandom
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root            60 2011-11-25 19:27 usb
crw-------   1 root root      252,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon0
crw-------   1 root root      252,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon1
crw-------   1 root root      252,   2 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon2
crw-------   1 root root      252,   3 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon3
crw-------   1 root root      252,   4 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon4
crw-------   1 root root      252,   5 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon5
crw-------   1 root root      252,   6 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon6
crw-------   1 root root      252,   7 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon7
crw-------   1 root root      252,   8 2011-11-25 19:28 usbmon8
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root            80 2011-11-25 19:28 v4l
crw-------   1 root root       10,  57 2011-11-25 19:28 vboxdrv
crw-------   1 root root       10,  56 2011-11-25 19:28 vboxnetctl
drwxr-x---   4 root vboxusers       80 2011-11-25 19:28 vboxusb
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 vcs
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7,   1 2011-11-25 19:28 vcs1
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7,   2 2011-11-25 19:28 vcs2
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7,   3 2011-11-25 19:28 vcs3
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7,   4 2011-11-25 19:28 vcs4
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7,   5 2011-11-25 19:28 vcs5
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7,   6 2011-11-25 19:28 vcs6
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7, 128 2011-11-25 19:28 vcsa
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7, 129 2011-11-25 19:28 vcsa1
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7, 130 2011-11-25 19:28 vcsa2
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7, 131 2011-11-25 19:28 vcsa3
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7, 132 2011-11-25 19:28 vcsa4
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7, 133 2011-11-25 19:28 vcsa5
crw-rw----   1 root tty         7, 134 2011-11-25 19:28 vcsa6
crw-------   1 root root       10,  63 2011-11-25 19:28 vga_arbiter
crw-rw----+  1 root video      81,   0 2011-11-25 19:28 video0
crw-rw-rw-   1 root root        1,   5 2011-11-25 19:28 zero
```

sg_scan -i gives me:

```
sudo sg_scan -i
/dev/sg0: scsi0 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em]
    ATA       ST31000524NS      SN12 [rmb=0 cmdq=0 pqual=0 pdev=0x0] 
/dev/sg1: scsi0 channel=0 id=1 lun=0 [em]
    ATA       WDC WD15EADS-00S  01.0 [rmb=0 cmdq=0 pqual=0 pdev=0x0] 
/dev/sg2: scsi2 channel=0 id=0 lun=0 [em]
    HL-DT-ST  BDDVDRW CH08LS10  2.00 [rmb=1 cmdq=0 pqual=0 pdev=0x5]
```

sg_map gives me:

```
/dev/sg0  /dev/sda
/dev/sg1  /dev/sdb
/dev/sg2  /dev/scd0
```

lsscsi -l gives me:

```
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST31000524NS     SN12  /dev/sda
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[0:0:1:0]    disk    ATA      WDC WD15EADS-00S 01.0  /dev/sdb
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=0 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
[2:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  HL-DT-ST BDDVDRW CH08LS10 2.00  /dev/sr0
  state=running queue_depth=1 scsi_level=6 type=5 device_blocked=0 timeout=30
```

my udf mod is:

```
filename:       /lib/modules/3.0.0-14-generic/kernel/fs/udf/udf.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Universal Disk Format Filesystem
author:         Ben Fennema
srcversion:     6ABDE012374D96B9685B8E5
depends:        crc-itu-t
vermagic:       3.0.0-14-generic SMP mod_unload modversions
```

Do I need special drivers or mods enabled? Do I need to change some BIOS settings?

edit:
Somehow I am now able to fire the mount command without any filesystem errors, but now I get:

```
mount: no medium found on /dev/sr0
```

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: You can delete it if you want. I have not found a solution. Damn the Bluray format!

Answer (score 5):

Did you try the udf type?

```
mount -t udf /dev/scd0 /media/bluray
```

Comment: As mentioned in my question I did try all filesystems mentioned in the manual of mount. I also tried CDs DVDs and Bluray-discs.

Comment: Ok, was the error when you used `-t udf` still "you must specify the filesystem type"? Is the udf module available? (`modinfo udf`)

Comment: it was "you must specify the filesystem type".