# Bluray drive not responding when inserting a disk

Tags: 12.04, mount, dvd, blu-ray

### Problem:

I am trying to play a bluray disk on my Sony Vaio Laptop running Ubuntu 12.04.2.
I have tried many tutorials on how to do this and actually I was able to play 1 scene once. But after reboot it stopped working again.

### What I have tried:

I did try anything suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9912/how-can-i-watch-blu-ray-discs) and also tried to [manually mount the disk](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82694/how-to-mount-a-blu-ray-drive). Both failed. I can run some termina command when no blu-ray is in the drive:

```
$wodim --devices
wodim: Overview of accessible drives (1 found) :
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 0  dev='/dev/sg1'  rwrw-- : 'PIONEER' 'BD-RW   BDR-TD04'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------

$ sudo lshw -c disk
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: BD-RW   BDR-TD04
       vendor: PIONEER
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
```

A *dmesg | tail* returns me many of these error blocks when a disk is inserted:

```
[ 2172.584143] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Unhandled sense code
[ 2172.584158] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 2172.584160] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[ 2172.584161] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 2172.584162] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[ 2172.584164] Info fld=0x0
[ 2172.584165] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 2172.584167] Add. Sense: L-EC uncorrectable error
[ 2172.584168] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 2172.584169] Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00
[ 2172.584173] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 0
[ 2172.584176] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 0
```

I found more on this issue [in an archlinux](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=740977) and [openSUSE](http://forums.opensuse.org/english/get-technical-help-here/hardware/452272-dvd-drive-stopped-working-11-3-a.html) forum but both questions did not help me. Without a disk in the drive all a *dmesg | grep sr0* returns is:

```
[    1.345366] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 62x/62x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.345556] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
```

*libdvdcss* is installed. So are *libbluray1*, *libbluray-dbg* and *libaacs0*. I also used [this guied to patch](http://vlc-bluray.whoknowsmy.name/) my *KEYDB.cfg* and my *libaacs0.so*

I also tried the [lxBDPlayer](http://lxbdplayer.sourceforge.net/english.html) without success.

### Question

I've read that this problem might be the result of a broken drive or a broken disk. The disk is brand new and should be fine (I also checked it for scratches etc.) and since the drive successfully plays audio-cds and DVDs I don't see how the drive can be broken. Is there anything you can suggest me to try. Any guide or tutorial you know about *how to run bluray on ubuntu* that I might have not tried yet?

If you need further information feel free to ask.

---

### Edit:

I just tried another bluray disk with the following result:
[image: error message]

Running *dmesg |grep sr0* returns still similar results:

```
$ dmesg |grep sr0
[    1.345366] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 62x/62x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
[    1.345556] sr 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
[ 7593.402746] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Unhandled sense code
[ 7593.402761] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 7593.402764] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 7593.402768] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 7593.402771] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 7593.402776] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1024
[ 7593.402779] Buffer I/O error on device sr0, logical block 128
[ 7607.672659] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] Unhandled sense code
[ 7607.672663] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 7607.672666] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 7607.672670] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0]  
[ 7607.672674] sr 4:0:0:0: [sr0] CDB: 
[ 7607.672679] end_request: I/O error, dev sr0, sector 1280
[ 7607.672695] UDF-fs: error (device sr0): udf_read_tagged: read failed, block=320, location=0
[ 7607.672699] UDF-fs: warning (device sr0): udf_fill_super: No fileset found
```

The drive is now responding to e.g. *lshw -c disk*

```
  *-cdrom
       description: DVD-RAM writer
       product: BD-RW   BDR-TD04
       vendor: PIONEER
       physical id: 0.0.0
       bus info: scsi@4:0.0.0
       logical name: /dev/cdrom
       logical name: /dev/cdrw
       logical name: /dev/dvd
       logical name: /dev/dvdrw
       logical name: /dev/sr0
       version: 1.00
       capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
       configuration: ansiversion=5 status=ready
     *-medium
      physical id: 0
      logical name: /dev/cdrom
```

I wonder why the name is **/dev/cdrom** and not **/dev/dvd**?
When I try to open the disk with VLC the following error pops up in the VLC console:

```
Blu-Ray error:
Path doesn't appear to be a bluray
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'bluray:///dev/cdrom'. Check the log for details.
```

Comment: Does it work if you insert a CD or an ordinary DVD, rather than a Blueray DVD? If so, you will have to look for a blueray driver. At the moment it is seen as DVD/CD peripheral.

Comment: Yes I am able to play normal CDs and DVDs just fine. Where can I find a blu-ray driver?

Comment: https://www.ebower.com/docs/ubuntu-bluray/ and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestrictedFormats/BluRayAndHDDVD may help

Comment: Hm. Both links are about makeMKV and seem to be quite outdated. I even read through the second one already without any success. Thank you for the links anyway.

Comment: I thought these drives have two laser readers: one for CDs and DVDs, and another for BluRay disks, so it might really be a broken drive. We could've confirmed this if you were dual booting...or if Windows had the concept of a live CD environment =/.

Comment: @Alaa I have a Windows 8 virtual machine. But unfortunately the BluRay support was removed in windows 8 and is only available if I purchase the windows 8 media pack.

Comment: We should also ponder the possibility of the disk using some non-free filesystem.

Comment: how can i find out what Kind oft encryption my disk is using? and if it is supported Ort not

Comment: I use a lame workaround. But well, this might still be helpful. I use Windows 7 and AnyDVDHD, 1:1 (w/o the copy protection) and work from there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a problem mounting Read-Only. CD's (DVD's, etc) *are* "read-only" discs, so mounting them read-only makes sense.

When you said that you've tried lxBDPlayer, did you also load the extra plugin, and software that makes work?

to use lxbdplayer, you will need to download the following:

- The [lxbdplayer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxbdplayer/files/ubuntu_deb/lxbdplayer_0.2.1_all.deb) itself. This package is a .deb for Ubuntu and
  Debian.
- The [AACSKeys](http://www.mediafire.com/?d1n3zyyhz2h) plugin for lxbdplayer.
- The [MakeMKV](http://www.mediafire.com/?rnjoym0q1q4) package (this is the 64-bit version. To get the
  32-bit version, click [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?mdimv3yobwo)).
- The [ShowKeys library](http://www.mediafire.com/?yz2yj3it3il) (this is the 64-bit version. To get the
  32-bit version, click [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?5ynetmrww21)).

To install the packages, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i lxbdplayer_0.2.1_all.deb lxbdaacs_0.2.1_all.deb makemkv_1.5.5b_amd64.deb libshowkeys_v1.5.5_amd64.deb
```

You might need to download a couple of dependencies, but otherwise the installation is small and quick.

Once the install is complete, import the decryption keys needed by typing in the following command:

```
bdkey-install
```

**Note**: You may need to have the drive’s firmware patched.

<sup>Source:The HyRax Macrocosm</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately I cannot install `lxbdaacs_0.2.1_all.deb` because of a blank line in the `.deb` file: *parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 12 package 'lxbdaacs':
 blank line in value of field 'Description*

Comment: Try downloading from [Here](http://4s.downtango.com/?d=q9d+DucSRgoq3wGAItcWV/US0w6k4QBGWsQ8zlkIcz7Obpz0rVn0ECW8yFG/igCoqoKaXxcuDoDQ2jarj/SEaxF7riDCP/tlByLD9GeImMigUOup1ZYy21SkBB+56dmC)

Comment: There are only `.exe` files to download. I downloaded one and renamed it. But it still did not work.

Comment: Sorry, I tried:)